# How to parse json with python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse some json data using python and am having trouble iterating through the different items.  It looks like all of the data is inside a list and there is a different dictionary for each item within the overall list.  This is what I have so far:

```
try:
        f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.reddit.com/r/videos/top/.json");
    except Exception:
        print("ERROR: malformed JSON response from reddit.com")
    reddit_posts = json.loads(f.read().decode("utf-8"))["data"]["children"][0]
    print reddit_posts["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"]
```

I can get the first url to show but I'm not sure how to iterate for all the items and show the urls.  Any advice?

Also, here is a better formatted view of the json I'm trying to parse: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.reddit.com/r/videos/top/.json

Edit:
I tried the for loop but am having trouble implementing it.

```
for entry in reddit_posts:
    print entry[0] #only prints the first character of entry ('k' and 'd')
    print entry["data"] #get an error: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: @Blender I tried putting a for loop in (it's in the edit) but am having trouble doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected only one post when you did `[0]` on the `["children"]` of the JSON result.

Therefore, to get *all* posts, leave off the `[0]`:

```
reddit_posts = json.loads(f.read().decode("utf-8"))["data"]["children"]
```

Now you can iterate over all of them:

```
for post in reddit_posts:
    print post["data"]["media"]["oembed"]["url"]
```

Comment: When I try that I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I'm able to see the url's in the command line, but the browser shows the error I mentioned above.